How to connect to emqx with scram authentication
I am using a emqx mqtt broker to create a server. I create two kind of authentication: SCRAM and Password-Based, and I added accounts in both authentication methods.
When I use spring-integration-mqtt to connect to emqx with SCRAM authentication, the server log shows:
2024-10-13T15:18:03.756773+00:00 [MQTT] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:57553 msg: mqtt_packet_received, packet: CONNECT(Q0, R0, D0, ClientId=ems_mqtt_client, ProtoName=MQTT, ProtoVsn=5, CleanStart=false, KeepAlive=60, Username=ems-api, Password=******), username: ems-api
2024-10-13T15:18:03.757916+00:00 [AUTHN] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:57553 msg: check_client_first_message_error, provider: emqx_authn_scram_mnesia, reason: other-error, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T15:18:03.758252+00:00 [AUTHN] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:57553 msg: authenticator_result, authenticator: scram:built_in_database, result: {error,not_authorized}, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T15:18:03.758661+00:00 [AUTHN] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:57553 msg: authentication_result, reason: chain_result, result: {stop,{error,not_authorized}}, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T15:18:03.754612+00:00 [warning] tag: AUTHN, clientid: ems_mqtt_client, msg: authentication_failure, peername: 192.168.65.1:57553, username: ems-api, reason: not_authorized
2024-10-13T15:18:03.760012+00:00 [MQTT] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:57553 msg: mqtt_packet_sent, packet: CONNACK(Q0, R0, D0, AckFlags=0, ReasonCode=135), username: ems-api
2024-10-13T15:18:03.760831+00:00 [SOCKET] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:57553 msg: emqx_connection_terminated, reason: {shutdown,not_authorized}, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T15:18:03.756641+00:00 [info] clientid: ems_mqtt_client, msg: terminate, peername: 192.168.65.1:57553, username: ems-api, reason: {shutdown,not_authorized}

when I user Password-Based authentication, everything is work well:
2024-10-13T16:04:07.554807+00:00 [MQTT] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: mqtt_packet_received, packet: CONNECT(Q0, R0, D0, ClientId=ems_mqtt_client, ProtoName=MQTT, ProtoVsn=5, CleanStart=false, KeepAlive=60, Username=ems-api, Password=******), username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.556182+00:00 [AUTHN] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: authenticator_result, authenticator: scram:built_in_database, result: ignore, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.557444+00:00 [AUTHN] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: authenticator_result, authenticator: password_based:built_in_database, result: {ok,#{is_superuser => false}}, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.557626+00:00 [AUTHN] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: authentication_result, reason: chain_result, result: {stop,{ok,#{is_superuser => false}}}, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.560195+00:00 [MQTT] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: mqtt_packet_sent, packet: CONNACK(Q0, R0, D0, AckFlags=0, ReasonCode=0), username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.572460+00:00 [MQTT] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: mqtt_packet_received, packet: SUBSCRIBE(Q1, R0, D0, PacketId=1 TopicFilters=[ems-lite-gateway(#{nl => 0,qos => 2,rap => 0,rh => 0})]), username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.573236+00:00 [AUTHZ] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: authorization_module_ignore, action: SUBSCRIBE(Q2), module: emqx_authz_client_info, topic: ems-lite-gateway, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.573750+00:00 [info] tag: AUTHZ, clientid: ems_mqtt_client, msg: authorization_permission_allowed, peername: 192.168.65.1:28273, username: ems-api, topic: ems-lite-gateway, action: SUBSCRIBE(Q2), source: 'authorization.no_match' config
2024-10-13T16:04:07.574054+00:00 [SUBSCRIBE] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: subscribe, sub_id: ems_mqtt_client, sub_opts: [nl: 0, qos: 2, rap: 0, rh: 0, sub_props: []], topic: ems-lite-gateway, username: ems-api
2024-10-13T16:04:07.575473+00:00 [MQTT] ems_mqtt_client@192.168.65.1:28273 msg: mqtt_packet_sent, packet: SUBACK(Q0, R0, D0, PacketId=1, ReasonCodes=[2]), username: ems-api


I set the connect properties use MqttConnectionOptions with below:
    @Bean
    public ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> mqttClientManager() {
        MqttConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new MqttConnectionOptions();
        if (mqttProperties.getAuthMethod() != null) {
            switch (mqttProperties.getAuthMethod()) {
                case USERNAME:
                    connectionOptions.setUserName(mqttProperties.getUsername());
                    connectionOptions.setPassword(mqttProperties.getPassword().getBytes());
                    break;
                case SCRAM_SHA_256:
                    log.debug("mqtt authentication with scram-sha-256");
                    connectionOptions.setAuthMethod(mqttProperties.getAuthMethod().name);
                    connectionOptions.setUserName(mqttProperties.getUsername());
                    connectionOptions.setPassword(mqttProperties.getPassword().getBytes());
                    connectionOptions.setAuthData("client-first-message".getBytes());
                    break;
            }
        }
        connectionOptions.setServerURIs(new String[]{mqttProperties.getHost()});
        connectionOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(mqttProperties.getKeepalive());
        connectionOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        connectionOptions.setAutomaticReconnectDelay(1, 5);
        connectionOptions.setConnectionTimeout(mqttProperties.getTimeout());
        connectionOptions.setCleanStart(false);
        String clientId = getClientId();
        Mqttv5ClientManager clientManager = new Mqttv5ClientManager(connectionOptions, clientId);
        log.info("mqtt url: {}, clientId: {}", mqttProperties.getHost(), clientId);
        return clientManager;
    }

I don't know how to configure connectionOptions.setAuthData();, and I don't know if the code about SCRAM above is correct or not.
I expecting program connect to emqx successfully by scram authentication. what should I do?
thank you very much!!!

can any body help me?
